# How to sort table by value using ng-if?

Tags: angularjs

I'm a novice at AngularJS and trying to get my table to only show the rows that have a '**color'** value of ***true*** when the user selects the ***'Color Only'*** item from the ***Sort By*** drop down menu.

Here's my sort menu code:

```
<label>Sort By:</label>
  <select ng-model="orderProp">
     <option value="title">Title</option>
     <option value="filename">File Name</option>
     <option value="class">Classification</option>
     <option value="color">Color Only</option>
  </select>
```

Here is my table code:

```
<table>

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Classification</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>File</th>
                    <th>Color</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-animate="'animate'" ng-repeat="item in filtered = (pptData | filter: query | orderBy: orderProp)">
                    <td>{{item.class | uppercase}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.title}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.filename}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.color}}</td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>
```

I tried adding ng-if="color"to the ng-repeat directive but that did not work. Live [**link here**](http://ogmda.com/symbols/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ng-if="orderProp !== 'color'  || item.color"
```

on your `ng-repeat` element.

As you should know, when you refer to a property in an Angular directive expression, the property is resolved against the current `$scope`. `ng-repeat` creates a child scope for every iteration. When you specify `ng-repeat="item in collection"`, you can then reference that child scope via the property `item`.

The `color` property is on that `item` child scope, *not* on the outer scope. Thus, saying `ng-if="color"` will result in none of the rows being rendered, because `$scope.color` is undefined. `ng-if="item.color"` will resolve against the `item` scope, and the row will only be rendered if `item.color` is defined.

However, if you only want to filter out those rows when the user has selected the `color` filtering option, you need to make sure you check the `orderProp`. Thus,

```
ng-if="orderProp !== 'color' || item.color"
```

gets the behavior you are looking for.

---

I suspect you will want to continue to do more complex filtering on these rows as you develop the code. In that case, I would recommend instead writing a function in your controller:

```
$scope.shouldShowRow = function(row, index) {
    var show = $scope . orderProp !== 'color" || row.color;
    // more logic for determining show/hide here
    return show;
}
```

And then in your template:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in (pptData | filter: query | orderBy: orderProp)"
    ng-if="shouldShowRow(item, $index)">
    <!-- your row markup here -->
</tr>
```

$index is a handy value that `ng-repeat` creates. You may not need it, but it might be useful.

---

As a suggestion, you should look into the `controllerAs` syntax. It requires you to name all of your controllers' scopes, and will help you keep track of what scope you are using when:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as my">
    ...
    <tr ng-repeat="item in (my.pptData | filter: query | orderBy: my.orderProp)"
        ng-if="my.shouldShowRow(item, $index)">
        ...
    </tr>
</div>
```

ControllerAs:
http://www.johnpapa.net/do-you-like-your-angular-controllers-with-or-without-sugar/

Comment: Edited initial answer; `ng-repeat` will re-render the DOM anyway so ng-show is not better than ng-if.

Comment: I'm lost at the "Your $scope does not have a color attribute; you have to refer to the individual item" comment. Can you explain a little bit more? Thanks.

Comment: I'll study your feedback and mark your answer as solved once I get it working. THanks.

Comment: So I got the behavior I wanted (only show COLOR rows if selecting the "Color Only" filter, but if I select any other value, Angular will hide the rest of the rows. I am not sure I am understanding how to only show the color rows if that is selected, but show all rows when any other value is selected. Thanks.

Comment: Should have been: `$scope.orderProp !== 'color' || row.color`,  not, `$scope.orderProp === 'color' && row.color`. Fixed it in the answer

Answer (score 0):

If your use-case permit, use `ng-show` instead of `ng-if` and you may see the orderBy working as expected.